# Create new class from appended string

Tags: php

Is it possible to do the following in one line? For instance, something like `$obj=new "entry_{$type}";`  Thanks

```
$class="entry_{$type}";
$obj=new $class();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534159/instantiate-a-class-from-a-variable-in-php

Comment: And of course it's so critical for code to be reduced to a single line wherever possible

Comment: Thanks all.  No, it wasn't so critical.  Just wanted to better understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but only if you really want it. It's a bit awkward:

```
$obj = new ${!${''}="entry_$type"}();
```

From: [Code-Golf: one line PHP syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011595/code-golf-one-line-php-syntax)

PHP wants to eventually [move to a proper parser](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/ast_based_parsing_compilation_process#request_for_commentsmoving_to_an_ast-based_parsingcompilation_process) that uses an Abstract Syntax Tree, which might tighten up syntax holes that currently prevent, for example, `new ("entry_$type")()` or something like that.

Comment: Egads!  It answers the question, but I will definitely stay with two lines!